# Why are the following Datalog programs equivalent?

Tags: datalog

For some existentional predicates a,b why is this:

```
q(X,Y) <-- a(X,Y), q(Z,Y)
q(X,Y) <-- b(X,Y)
```

equivalent to this:

```
q(X,Y) <-- a(X,Y), b(Z,Y)
q(X,Y) <-- b(X,Y)
```

?
Why can't the top recursion just continue to expand?

Comment: How far could the top recursion expand?

Comment: @Marcelo: Assuming q(Z,Y) already holds, does showing that q(X,Y) also holds open up any additional solutions for q?

Comment: @Anon: I think I figured it out (see my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand the first clause once, you get `a(X,Y), a(Z,Y), b(Z′,Y)`. Since *Z* is free, `a(Z,Y)` is a simple existential quantifier on *Y*, which has already been asserted by the first clause, so the expression collapses to `a(X,Y), b(Z′,Y)`, which is of course equivalent to `a(X,Y), b(Z,Y)`, since *Z′* is also a free variable.